# converting array of strings to single row values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have records in Big Query table as
name        value
Aashis    ["AB",AC"]
Rahul     ["AA",AD"]

Here name and value column is String Type

I want the output as
name   value
Aashis AB
Aashis AC
Rahul  AA
Rahul  AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(value) value
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Aashis' name, ["AB","AC"] value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Rahul', ["AA","AD"]
)
SELECT name, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(value) value
```

with result

```
Row name    value    
1   Aashis  AB   
2   Aashis  AC   
3   Rahul   AA   
4   Rahul   AD
```

> Update for: the column value is of Type String and Unnest accepts array.How do I convert this column to array ?

See below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Aashis' name, '["AB","AC"]' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Rahul', '["AA","AD"]'
)
SELECT name, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, r'^\[|]$', ''))) value
```

with result

```
Row name    value    
1   Aashis  "AB"     
2   Aashis  "AC"     
3   Rahul   "AA"     
4   Rahul   "AD"
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the answer. Here the column value is of Type String and Unnest accepts array.How do I convert this column to array ?

Comment: you clearly stated in your question that you have an `array of string`. so looks like this is not a case! i will update the answer shortly