# Failed to Implement Array to String using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to try to change my array into string and transpose it exactly like this thread about [converting-array-of-strings-to-single-row-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628342/converting-array-of-strings-to-single-row-values) but I failed when trying to implement it.

my array have some data like:

```
Claimers = ["140","119","120","121","122","123","126","127"]
userId = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

the length itself is around 60, I try to use `UNNEST` and `concat_ws` but still failed

this is my query when using `UNNEST`:

```
SELECT `Code`, `Used`, `Claimers` AS aClaim FROM referal, UNNEST(aClaim) aClaim
```

and this is my query when using concat_ws:

```
SELECT `Code`, `Used`, concat_ws(',', `Claimers`) AS aClaim FROM referal
```

I want my output look like this:

```
1 140
1 119
2 120
2 122
2 123
3 121
3 126
4 127
```

can someone help me to tell where I failed to implement the technique?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MYSQL for dbms

Comment: I've removed the phpmyadmin tag because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNNEST function in MYSQL like POSTGRESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364788/unnest-function-in-mysql-like-postgresql)