# Unable to unnest in bigquery when there is comma inside list which is of type string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

Unable to unnest in bigquery when there is comma inside list which is of type string. I have data in following format where value is type of string

```
name value
Aashis ["A,B",AC"]
Rahul ["AA",AD"]
```

When I use following query, It is incorrectly splitting and unable to get logic right in regexp_replace

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Aashis' name, '["A,B","AC"]' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Rahul', '["AA","AD"]'
)
SELECT name, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, r'^\[|]$', ''))) value
```

With the above code, I am getting

```
Aashis A
Aashis B
Aashis AC
Rahul AA
Rahul AD
```

My expected output is

```
Aashis AB
Aashis AC
Rahul AA
Rahul AD
```

I have followed following link [converting array of strings to single row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628342/converting-array-of-strings-to-single-row-values)

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Aashis' name, '["A,B","AC"]' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Rahul', '["AA","AD"]'
)
SELECT name, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, r'^\[|]$', ''), '"'),'","')) value
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below less verbose option

```
SELECT name, TRIM(new_value, '"') new_value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, r'".*?"')) new_value
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]